# Spontaneously movings when there are multiple photon view objects

Tags: unity-game-engine, photon

I am making game like jenga blocks that players can take ownership and drag blocks when their turn.

But blocks sliding itself and fall down after i added transform view and rigidbody view on each blocks. How can i fix this problem?

Comment: Make sure to only have the rigidbody & collider components on the master client. Disable or removed them for other clients.

Comment: But even only 1 player connected still same problem. I tried remove rigidbody from other client but it didnt work.